# Rabin cryptosystem with 1 mod 4

Tags: encryption, rabin-cryptosystem

We have p and q which are distinct primes congruent to 1 mod 4. Then we have n = p*q.

Do you know any algorith for calculating square roots for the decryption in this case? I'm asking for some explanation how to calculate or some pseudocode. Thanks in advance

Comment: Anything precise that you do not get in [algorithm 3.44 of the HAC](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap3.pdf#page=17)?

Comment: Square a is our cipher in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_cryptosystem#Decryption? How to tell if b is quadratic non-residue mod p? Is it enough to compute b from equation in Algorithm 3.39 point 1?

Comment: If you are lucky, $p\equiv q\equiv5\pmod8$ and you can use Alg 3.37. Otherwise, you have to use Alg 3.39 for $r$ or/and $s$;  in its point 1, you need [Alg 2.149](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap2.pdf#page=26) in order to compute the Jacobi symbol $\Big({b^2-4a\over p}\Big)$.

Comment: There is a a new solution for constraints m={13,20,57,64} in Michael O. Rabin Cryptosystem(https://www.ijser.org/onlineResearchPaperViewer.aspx?A-mathematical-model-for-ascertaining-same-ciphertext-generated-from-distinct-plaintext-in-Michael-O-Rabin-Cryptosystem.pdf) - disclosure, I'm the author.